# Hi. I'm trying to run this query in developer console and I keep getting Unexpected token "SELECT"

Tags: soql

```
SELECT 
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__c,
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__r.Name, 
    COUNT(DMAPP__Contact__c)
FROM 
    DMAPP__DM_Political_Map_Contact__c
GROUP BY 
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__c,
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__r.Name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(DMAPP__Contact__c) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to run this query in the Execute Anonymous window, rather than in the SOQL editor window.

That said, if you want to run this query via apex execute anonymous, you've got to write the apex structure to do it:

```
List<AggregateResult> records = [
SELECT 
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__c,
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__r.Name, 
    COUNT(DMAPP__Contact__c)
FROM 
    DMAPP__DM_Political_Map_Contact__c
GROUP BY 
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__c,
    DMAPP__DM_Opportunity_Extra__r.DMAPP__Opportunity__r.Name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(DMAPP__Contact__c) DESC];

System.debug(records); // or do something else with your records collection
```

Comment: Thank you.  This helped.  :)

Comment: shouldn't the query result be a `List<AggregateResult>` ?

Comment: Good catch @cropredy